# Use GHCi breakpoint debugger to find intermediate results?

Tags: debugging, haskell, lazy-evaluation

Is it possible to stop the GHCi debugger when the result of a function is known?

For example, consider the following snippet of code:

```
blabla    :: [Int] -> Int
bla       :: Int -> Int
papperlap :: Int -> Int -> Int

bla x         = x+x
papperlap y x = ((y *) . bla) x
blabla xs     = foldl papperlap 0 x
```

Now, I would like to see the results of 'papperlap' and 'bla'. But remember I want to stop when the result is evaluated. Therefore using ':force' is out of the question since it changes the order of evaluation.

When I use ':break' the debugger stops but _result is not yet evaluated yet. Please find my GHCi session below, which does not yield the desired intermediate results:

```
GHCi, version 7.6.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( bla1.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main> :break blabla
Breakpoint 0 activated at bla1.hs:7:1-36
*Main> :break papperlap
Breakpoint 1 activated at bla1.hs:6:1-31
*Main> :break bla
Breakpoint 2 activated at bla1.hs:5:1-19
*Main> blabla [1,2,3]
Stopped at bla1.hs:7:1-36
_result :: Int = _
[bla1.hs:7:1-36] *Main> :step
Stopped at bla1.hs:7:17-36
_result :: Int = _
xs :: [Int] = [1,2,3]
[bla1.hs:7:17-36] *Main> :step
Stopped at bla1.hs:6:1-31
_result :: Int = _
[bla1.hs:6:1-31] *Main> :step
Stopped at bla1.hs:6:17-31
_result :: Int = _
x :: Int = 3
y :: Int = _
[bla1.hs:6:17-31] *Main> :step
Stopped at bla1.hs:6:1-31
_result :: Int = _
[bla1.hs:6:1-31] *Main> :step
Stopped at bla1.hs:6:17-31
_result :: Int = _
x :: Int = 2
y :: Int = _
[bla1.hs:6:17-31] *Main> :step
Stopped at bla1.hs:6:1-31
_result :: Int = _
[bla1.hs:6:1-31] *Main> :step
Stopped at bla1.hs:6:17-31
_result :: Int = _
x :: Int = 1
y :: Int = 0
[bla1.hs:6:17-31] *Main> :step
Stopped at bla1.hs:5:1-19
_result :: Int = _
[bla1.hs:5:1-19] *Main> :step
Stopped at bla1.hs:5:17-19
_result :: Int = _
x :: Int = 1
[bla1.hs:5:17-19] *Main> :step
Stopped at bla1.hs:5:1-19
_result :: Int = _
[bla1.hs:5:1-19] *Main> :step
Stopped at bla1.hs:5:17-19
_result :: Int = _
x :: Int = 2
[bla1.hs:5:17-19] *Main> :step
Stopped at bla1.hs:5:1-19
_result :: Int = _
[bla1.hs:5:1-19] *Main> :step
Stopped at bla1.hs:5:17-19
_result :: Int = _
x :: Int = 3
[bla1.hs:5:17-19] *Main> :step
0
*Main>
```

Answer (score 3):

Might be a bit late for your immediate debugging concerns, but here's what I would do:

```
blabla    :: [Int] -> Int
bla       :: Int -> Int
papperlap :: Int -> Int -> Int

bla x         = (undefined :: Int)
papperlap y x = ((y *) . bla) x
blabla xs = foldl papperlap 0 xs
```

Now we know we'll get an exception in the evaluation of `bla`. So let's drop into ghci:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( temp.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
λ: :set -fbreak-on-exception
λ: :trace blabla [1,5,17]
Stopped at <exception thrown>
_exception :: e = _
λ: :hist
-1  : bla (temp.hs:6:17-35)
-2  : bla (temp.hs:6:1-35)
-3  : papperlap (temp.hs:7:17-31)
-4  : papperlap (temp.hs:7:1-31)
-5  : papperlap (temp.hs:7:17-31)
-6  : papperlap (temp.hs:7:1-31)
-7  : papperlap (temp.hs:7:17-31)
-8  : papperlap (temp.hs:7:1-31)
-9  : blabla (temp.hs:8:13-32)
-10 : blabla (temp.hs:8:1-32)
<end of history>
λ: :back
Logged breakpoint at temp.hs:6:17-35
_result :: a
λ: :list
5
6  bla x         = (undefined :: Int )
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
7  papperlap y x = ((y *) . bla) x
λ: :back
Logged breakpoint at temp.hs:6:1-35
_result :: a
λ: :list
5
6  bla x         = (undefined :: Int )
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
7  papperlap y x = ((y *) . bla) x
λ: :back
Logged breakpoint at temp.hs:7:17-31
_result :: Int
x :: Int
y :: Int
λ: :list
6  bla x         = (undefined :: Int )
7  papperlap y x = ((y *) . bla) x
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
8  blabla xs = foldl papperlap 0 xs
```

And so we can see the stack leading up to the evaluation of the right-hand-side of `bla`.

This isn't perfect, since  putting in `undefined`s everywhere seems tacky and hacky, but `:hist` gives you quite a bit to work on already, and using `:list` as you step back makes things even clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Haskell doesn't step through literal expressions for you. Something like

```
e = 2*(2+2)
```

will immediately evaluate to 8, because the compiler will optimize any expressions composed of  literals it can find just 'laying around' at compile time (this type of expression is called a constant applicative form).

Now you have to realize that `foldl` is lazy. If you call `foldl f` on a list, it won't perform a single evaluation of `f` until it is absolutely forced to do so.

```
>foldl (+) 0 [1,2,3] 
>foldl (+) a1 [2,3]
     where a1 = 0+1
>foldl (+) a2 [3]
     where a2 = a1+2
           where a1 = 0+1
```

eventually we have `((0+1)+2)+3)` and the compiler says "ok, we have exhausted every list and expanded every evaluation to the most primitive form we can. lets evaluate". And we already know that Haskell *won't* step through the evaluation of a CAF.

If you want to see the intermediate values of the evaluation you have to actually produce them first place. The way you do this is the following strict variant of `foldl`:

```
foldl' f z []     = z
foldl' f z (x:xs) = let z' = z `f` x 
                    in seq z' $ foldl' f z' xs
```

I will leave you to figure out how it works, but `seq a b` will fully evalutate `a` before continuing to lazily evaluate `b`.

Do everything else as before, except change `foldl` to `foldl'`. When you step through the evaluation, you will see intermediate when you are paused inside the `foldl'` function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, switching to strict evaluation is not what I desire, in that case I could also use ':force'. 

My intention is to be able to inspect the result of 'bla' and 'papperlap' when their result values have been evaluated.

And to abtain a result similar to:

`bla 1 = 2; 
papperlap 0 1 = 0;
bla 2 = 4;
papperlap 0 2 = 0;
bla 3 = 6;
papperlap 0 3 = 0;
blabla [1,2,3] = 0`